# What is the correct way to implement error propagation in C?

Tags: c, exception, error-handling, error-code, return-code

I come from high-level languages with exceptions (C#, in particular), and I usually only catch exceptions that my logic knows how to handle — otherwise, they propagate and program crashes, but at least it provides a clear information about what happened, and where. I want to implement similar behavior in C. I want, in the small body of my `main`, to get an error code from the functions that I call, to identify what happened, and to print error message to `stderr` and quit with the same error code as I got.

1. First question — do people do that in C, and is it a good objective, in terms of architecture, at all?
2. Seconds question is about error return codes and errno. What should I use in my code by default? It seems that these two conventions are used interchangeably in C standard library, and it's pretty confusing.
3. Third question is about error codes themselves. In C# and Java, there are standard exception types that cover almost everything you would typically throw, apart from specific comments. Should I use errno error code table for this purpose, or should I create a separate error code table for my application to include all stuff that it specific to it? Or may be every function should maintain it's own specific table of error codes?
4. And finally, additional information about errors: I found that in C#, at least, it's very useful to be able to throw an exception of predefined type with a specific comment that provides additional information. Is something like this used in C error management? How should I implement it?
5. Why do library functions use return codes **and** errno at the same time instead of sticking to one or the other? What's the benefit in using both?

Comment: If all you want to do is print the error message and quit, then `main` doesn't look like the right place to do that. Write an error handling function and call it whenever a fatal error occurs, from the place you detect it. OTOH if you want to clean up and continue, you may need something more involved.

Comment: Whoever flagged this question as "too broad", I would love to hear your thoughts about why is it too broad and how this question could be improved in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

It seems, you can make use of [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) variable and [`perror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) functions. They help to provide the reason for failure for *most* of the time.

Most of the library functions, to indicate the failure, will *usually* return a prefixed negative value (mostly `-1`) and set the `errno` variable to a particular value, depending on the type of the error.

> *is it normally used for this purpose?*

Yes, that is the purpose for having `errno` and `perror()`, IMHO.

Now, in case of user-defined functions, you can create own error codes for the errors returned by the library functions (with some time of mapping) and you can return your own value from your function.

---

EDIT:

> *What's the benefit in using both?*

To differentiate the reason for failure, in case of a failure event, in an easy way.

Think it like this, instead of having a fixed reurn value for error and setting errno, if a function returns different values for each type of error,  then how many `if-else` or `switch` statements you'll need for checking the success of the called function, each time it's called?  It's huge.

Rather, use a fixed return value to indicate error and if error, then check the errno for the reason behind the error.

<sup>[Hope I'm clear. English is not my native language, sorry]</sup>

Comment: I know that I can; but the question is, is it normally used for this purpose? How do experienced C developers make decisions about whether to use or not to use errno for it?

Comment: OK, reason behind the disagreement? Any counter-logics? Comment for downvote?

Comment: "how many if-else or switch statements you'll need for checking the success of the called function?" One, `if (dostuff() == 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding: *I want, in the small body of my main, to get an error code from the functions that I call, to identify what happened, and to print error message to stderr and quit with the same error code as I got*

> First question — do people do that in C, and is it a good objective,
>   in terms of architecture, at all?

***Some*** people do this, but ***All*** people should.  It is considered good form

> Seconds question is about error return codes and errno. What should I
>   use in my code by default? It seems that these two conventions are
>   used interchangeably in C standard library, and it's pretty confusing.

See first answer.  It covers this well. (+1 to @Sourav)

> Third question is about error codes themselves. In C# and Java, there
>   are standard exception types that cover almost everything you would
>   typically throw, apart from specific comments. Should I use errno
>   error code table for this purpose, or should I create a separate error
>   code table for my application to include all stuff that it specific to
>   it? Or may be every function should maintain it's own specific table
>   of error codes?

***This is completely up to the developer***.  When creating an application, I will use specific error codes/messages native to the library call that generated the condition.  When I create an API (usually .dll) I will often create a single enum containing all possible return conditions specific to the application, and will integrate C native library errors into this enum as well. Zero/Positive values for success conditions, and negative for error conditions.  Along with that I create an array of string descriptions corresponding to each return condition.  These are callable by the application via a function, eg. `int GetErrorDescription(int error, char *str);`.  However, this can be approached several different ways, this is just my approach.

***Example:***

```
/*------------------------------------------
//List of published error codes
/*-----------------------------------------*/
enum    {
    SUCCESS                        =  0,
    COPYFILE_ERR_1                 = -1,   //"CopyFile() error. File not found or directory in path not found.",
    COPYFILE_ERR_3                 = -2,   //"CopyFile() error. General I/O error occurred.",
    COPYFILE_ERR_4                 = -3,   //"CopyFile() error. Insufficient memory to complete operation.",
    COPYFILE_ERR_5                 = -4,   //"CopyFile() error. Invalid path or target and source are same.",
    COPYFILE_ERR_6                 = -5,   //"CopyFile() error. Access denied.",
    ...
    FOPEN_ERR_EIO                  = -11,  //"fopen() error. I/O error.",
    FOPEN_ERR_EBADF                = -12,  //"fopen() error. Bad file handle.",
    FOPEN_ERR_ENOMEM               = -13,  //"fopen() error. Insufficient memory.",
    ...
    GETFILESIZE_ERR_3              = -24,  //"GetFileSize() error - Insufficient memory to complete operation.",
    GETFILESIZE_ERR_4              = -25,  //"GetFileSize() error - Invalid path or target and source are same.",
    GETFILESIZE_ERR_5              = -26,  //"GetFileSize() error - Access denied.",
    ...
    PATH_MUST_BE_C_DRIVE           = -38,  //"SaveFile path variable must contain \"c:\\\".",
    HEADER_FIELD_EMPTY             = -39,  //"one or more of the header fields are incorrect or empty.",
    HEADER_FIELD_ILLEGAL_COMMA     = -40,  //"one or more of the header fields contains a comma.",
    ...
    MAX_ERR                        =  46   // defines the size of the static char ErrMsg
};
```

***And*** then a function to get the description:

```
int API GetErrorMessage (int err, char * retStr)
{
    //verify arguments are not NULL
    if(retStr == NULL)
    {
        return UNINIT_POINTER_ARGUMENT;
    }
    switch(err) {
        case  COPYFILE_ERR_1               : strcpy(retStr, "CopyFile() error. File not found or directory in path not found."     ); break;
        case  COPYFILE_ERR_3               : strcpy(retStr, "CopyFile() error. General I/O error occurred."                        ); break;
        case  COPYFILE_ERR_4               : strcpy(retStr, "CopyFile() error. Insufficient memory to complete operation."         ); break;
        case  COPYFILE_ERR_5               : strcpy(retStr, "CopyFile() error. Invalid path or target and source are same."        ); break;
        case  COPYFILE_ERR_6               : strcpy(retStr, "CopyFile() error. Access denied."                                     ); break;
        ...
        case  FOPEN_ERR_EIO                : strcpy(retStr, "fopen() error. I/O error."                                            ); break;
        case  FOPEN_ERR_EBADF              : strcpy(retStr, "fopen() error. Bad file handle."                                      ); break;
        case  FOPEN_ERR_ENOMEM             : strcpy(retStr, "fopen() error. Insufficient memory."                                  ); break;
        ...
        case  GETFILESIZE_ERR_3            : strcpy(retStr, "GetFileSize() error - Insufficient memory to complete operation."     ); break;
        case  GETFILESIZE_ERR_4            : strcpy(retStr, "GetFileSize() error - Invalid path or target and source are same."    ); break;
        case  GETFILESIZE_ERR_5            : strcpy(retStr, "GetFileSize() error - Access denied."                                 ); break;
        ...
        case  HEADER_FIELD_EMPTY           : strcpy(retStr, " one or more of the header fields are incorrect or empty."        ); break;
        case  HEADER_FIELD_ILLEGAL_COMMA   : strcpy(retStr, " one or more of the header fields contains a comma."              ); break;
        case  EVENT_FIELD_EMPTY            : strcpy(retStr, " one or more of the event fields is incorrect or empty."          ); break;
        case  EVENT_FIELD_ILLEGAL_COMMA    : strcpy(retStr, " one or more of the event fields contains a comma."               ); break;
        ...
        default:   strcpy(retStr, ""); break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> And finally, additional information about errors: I found that in C#,
>   at least, it's very useful to be able to throw an exception of
>   predefined type with a specific comment that provides additional
>   information. Is something like this used in C error management? How
>   should I implement it?

***comment addressing previous question*** also addresses this.

> Why do library functions use return codes and errno at the same time
>   instead of sticking to one or the other? What's the benefit in using
>   both?

***again***, covered by Sourav.

Comment: "Positive values for success conditions" — doesn't it contradict the C convention of returning 0 on success? Having many ways to fail and only one way to succeed seems like a very reasonable convention to me.

Comment: "comment addressing previous question also addresses this." I don't think that we're talking about the same thing here. You seem to be talking to a general error description string that looks like "File read error", and I'm talking about a string with specific information, like "Error reading mystuff.txt from open_file() function at 15:24:34". The error code `FILE_OPEN_ERROR` is the same, but I want to capture the specifics too.

Comment: But thanks for the answer — that's exactly the **type** of answer I was looking for.

Comment: @MaxYankov -  First comment - Yes, for this particular API, I choose a convention, and published it via the header file.  APIs other than the standard C libraries have not settled on a hard convention for positive/negative.  Each established their own.  It depends completely on the developer.  This is why I combine error conditions for all libraries into one exception handling table, to present to the user of the API a consistent set of error conditions ***specific only*** to the API.

Comment: @MaxYankov -  Second comment - When I want more detailed information about an exception, such as time-stamping, I use the string representation , say from the GetErrorDescription() function, and pass it to a logging routine, in which I can package a log entry to contain the API error description, a time-stamp, and any other information that is relevant, such as what calling function did this error occur in.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, exception-type behavior isn't done in C.  The convention is that the return value of each function is expected to be checked and handled by the immediate caller, along with any ancillary variable (such as errno) that the function may set.

That being said, you could do something similar to exceptions by using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.  You use `setjmp()` to set a jump point, passing in a `jmp_buf` structure to save the jump point.  Later on in the code, no matter how far down the call stack, you can pass that `jmpbuf` to `longjmp()` which will result in control going back up to where `setjmp()` was called.  You also pass a value to `longjmp()` which will be the return value of `setjmp()`.  You can then use this value as a lookup into an error table to print a more detailed message.

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/longjmp) other questions related to `longjmp()` that you can read up on.

EDIT:

An example:

```
jmp_buf jbuf;

void some_function()
{
   ...
   if (some_error()) {
     longjmp(jbuf, 2);
     /* control never gets here */
   }
   ...
}

void run_program()
{
  ...
  some_function();
  ...
}

int main()
{
  int rval;
  if ((rval=setjmp(jbuf)) == 0) {
    run_program();
  } else {
    /* rval will be 2 if the error in some_function() is triggered */
    printf("error %d: %s\n", rval, get_err_string(rval));
  }
}
```

Comment: `setjmp/longjmp` are plain C, so there is no need to restrict that to POSIX systems.

Comment: I don't think you read the question carefully. I didn't propose to implement exceptions in C; I was only asking about error propagation.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks, I removed the restriction from my answer.

Comment: @MaxYankov If you want to propagate errors back to main for handling, anytime you call a function you'll need to check the return value and return that value up to its caller.  So each function would need to keep track of its own normal return values in addition to error values returned by calling functions.  With `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`, you don't need to worry about any of that.